# Is there any alternative to using sudo with unison -owner?

Tags: permissions, unison

I have been using Unison to sync my data among several computers, and I am now trying to extend my scheme to include other users' home directories (other family members).

But I would like to preserve the files' owner (and group) attributes, so I presumably need to use the unison -owner (and -group) options.

But as only the root user can `chown` files, do I *have* to `sudo unison`? I am a bit reluctant to do that! Or is there another way? (kubuntu 18.04 and 20.04)

Comment: Why not have each of your family members run Unison themselves when they're logged in? (you could write their Unison profiles and add a line to their autostart list for them) Otherwise, yeah, if you want to touch users' files other than you're own, that's a pretty Super User thing to DO.